# Laravel Mailer - PHPUnit Testing - Mocking not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to unit test some events that fire emails. In particular, I want to test the emails are being sent.

The error is that getTransport() doesn't exist on the mocked object.
I added shouldReceive('getTransport') but then I'd have to mock what it returns too and then the function that is called on the mock object that is returned... etc etc.

My code in my Event listener:

```
    $data = compact('pusher', 'product', 'time', 'contact');
    Mail::send('emails.sms.oos', $data, function($message) {
        $message->to('ben@me.com')->subject('');
        $message->from('me@newaverfid.com');
    });
```

My Test:

```
    // Set the expected calls
    $mock->shouldReceive('send')
        ->once()
        ->with(
            'emails.sms.oos',
            m::on(function ($data) {
                $this->assertArrayHasKey('pusher', $data);
                return true;
            }),
            m::on( function(\Closure $closure) use ($location, $client, $contact, $reader, $pusher){
                $message = m::mock('Illuminate\Mailer\Message');
                $message->shouldReceive('to')->once()->with($contact->cellEmail())
                    ->andReturn($message);
                $message->shouldReceive('subject')->once()->with('');
                $message->shouldReceive('from')->once()->with('me@newaverfid.com');
                $closure($message);
                return true;
            })
        );
```

And... my error:

```
1) InventoryEventsTest::it_only_emails_contacts_for_the_specific_location
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_1_Swift_Mailer::getTransport() does not exist on this mock object

C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:315
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:159
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:222
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\app\Listeners\SMSInventoryOutOfStockNotification.php:47
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\app\Listeners\SMSInventoryOutOfStockNotification.php:47
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\tests\Integrated\InventoryEventsTest.php:157
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the mock a [partial mock](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/242), so you're only mocking the methods you need to mock (in your case the Mail::send() method). Calls to methods that do not have defined expectations, in your case the getTransport() method for instance, will instead be called on the parent "unmocked" class of the mock. You can specify the partial mock like this:

If the mock is a variable:

```
$mock->makePartial();
```

Directly specified on the facade:

```
Mail::makePartial();
```

The makePartial() method should be called after the expectations have been defined.

Comment: When I do that, I get a new error **Fatal error: Call to a member function stop() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\newdash\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php on line 315**

Comment: Then your expectation must be incorrect (the arguments in the with()-method does not match what is actually sent in) so it's using the real send() method instead of your mock. If you change your mock to `$mock->shouldReceive('send')->once();`, will this work?

Comment: Yes, it works with just `->shouldReceive('send')->once()` but not all the other methods... guess I'll play around with it more...